# testing a widget using Monkey

Tags: android, testing, monkey

I am trying to run Monkey Test on a Widget for my application. 
The package for my app is com.myapp.mycompany.appstore
and package for my widget is com.myapp.mycompany.appstore.appwidget

I have intent category listed in my Manifest by still I get an error as :

:IncludeCategory: android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
:IncludeCategory: android.intent.category.MONKEY
** No activities found to run, monkey aborted.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a widget is not an Activity at all, so it should not be Monkey Testable.

Comment: You might have some success with MonkeyRunner. I don't believe that is restricted to just activities. Unfortunately, I've never tried it on a widget, so I don't really know for sure.